# rspec check if one method calls another method

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm very stuck when it comes to writing a test to check if an instance variable equals a certain value then it should call a certain method, and that if it is less than that value, then it should not. I have an instance variable, @counter, which is initialized at 0, and these methods:

```
def increment_counter
     @counter += 1

     if @counter == 9
        tie_game?
     end
end

def tie_game?
    puts "The game was a tie. Nicely played #{@player1} & #{@player2}!"
    play_again  
end
```

I want to write a test to check that when @counter equals 9, that tie_game? is called, and that when it is less than 9, it is not called.

This is what I could come up with, but it is wrong:

```
describe "increment_counter" do
    context "counter equals 9" do
        it "calls tie_game?" do
            game.instance_variable_set(:@counter, 9)
            expect(increment_counter).to receive(:tie_game?)

        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check whether `tie_game?` was called on the `game` instance and not on `increment_counter`. With the code you have given, one way to do this would be

```
describe "increment_counter" do
  context 'counter equals 9' do
    let(:game) { Game.new }
    it 'calls tie_game?' do
      game.instance_variable_set(:@counter, 8)
      game.increment_counter
      expect(game).to receive(:tie_game?)
    end

    it 'does not call tie_game?' do
      game.increment_counter
      expect(game).not_to receive(:tie_game?)  
    end
end
```

end

I am assuming that your class name is `Game`. Since both your examples require a `game` instance, we can dry it up and use `let` to define the game instance. Note that `let` is `lazily evaluated`. Meaning its only executed when its referenced in the example block. If you set your instance variable to 0 in the `initialize` method, the tests will work fine.

Note that I am setting `@counter` to 8 and then I am triggering `increment_counter` method to test whether it calls `tie_game?`

PS: Should `tie_game` be a boolean method? Does `play_again` return a boolean.I am not sure if it should be a boolean method.

Comment: thanks for your advice. This seems to be working, but when I run it in the terminal, before it tells me about any failures, it runs the play_again method. Do you know how I should go about making sure it does not do that?